# Finding a post mentioning different kinds of continuity

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reference-request

A long time ago, I saw a post asking about the definitions of other types of continuities besides uniform and Lipschitz ones. If I remember correctly, the answer in that post mentions up to 6 kinds of continuity.

I have searched but have not found it. Could you please give a the link to that post?

Thank you so much!

Comment: It's weir, but I've just found it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097074/book-on-lipschitz-continuity/2097121).

Comment: Probably best to make that an answer to your question (you can self answer) and accept it; it keeps the site tidier :)

Comment: Thank you @postmortes! I did it :)

Comment: Also [approximate continuity](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22approximate+continuity%22), [symmetric continuity](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22symmetric+continuity%22), [qualitative continuity](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22qualitative+continuity%22%20+%20%22Marcus%22), [preponderant continuity](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22preponderant+continuity%22), [Darboux continuity](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Darboux+continuity%22), [density continuity](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22density+continuity%22), and I could continue with many more but I'm at my character limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the post at [Book on Lipschitz continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097074/book-on-lipschitz-continuity/2097121). I post it as an answer to peacefully close this question.

Comment: Since you found the answer, and posted it, I invite you to accept your answer!  That's the most peaceful manner in which to signal "an answer has been found!" :-)

Comment: There is a limit of 48 hours before I'm able to accept my own answer @amWhy :(

Comment: Well, then it's not too late!  I'll look forward to your acceptance of your answer tomorrow!

Comment: Hi @amWhy, I have asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3562478/how-to-prove-left-langle-nabla-f-leftx-star-right-v-x-star-right-rang). If you don't mind, please help me answer it!